# call pydev server from custom eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, pydev

I am trying to build an eclipse plugin and want to start PyDev debugger server locally. Is it possible to make a call like this?

Calling the pydev server from the Handler's execute method:

```
@Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        //call PyDev Debug server from here
        PydevRemoteDebuggerServer.startServer();
}
```

But, I'm getting an unsupported version error. (Tried updating the version on the class path and build. Yet, it results in same issue). Is the approach wrong or is it because of the variations in versions?

Please, correct me on this.

Comment: Please include your actual stack trace.

Comment: I'm now able to call pydev server locally. Unsupported version error is caused by other SWT Widget code. Previously, I've only added debug.jar. Later, when other jars - core.jar, pydev-debug.jar, shared_core.jar were added to the plugin, I could finally start the Remote Debugger Server. Thanks @Fabio Zadrozny for exposing PydevRemoteDebuggerServer API.

Answer (score 0):

Add all the required pydev plugin jars. Though, I just wanted to start Pydev's Remote Debugger Server locally there are few other dependencies that needs to be handled.

Best way is to add these jars -

1. core.jar
2. pydev-debug.jar
3. shared_core.jar
4. debug.jar

Note: Update the class path after adding the jars.

Comment: As a note ,if you have a plugin which depends on the pydev plugin, just adding the needed plugin references to the MANIFEST.MF should do the trick (without fiddling manually with the classpath).

Comment: @Fabio Zadrozny. So, In the MANIFEST.MF file adding the references as below will work? Require-Bundle: 
 org.python.pydev;bundle-version="[5.3.1,5.3.2)",
 org.python.pydev.core;bundle-version="[5.3.1,5.3.2)",
 org.eclipse.debug.ui,
 org.python.pydev.debug;bundle-version="[5.3.1,5.3.2)"]

Comment: Haven't tested it here, but yes, that's the idea -- the versions are actually optional (i.e.: you may leave them open if you don't want to update them at each new PyDev release).

Comment: As suggested, I have tried using the pydev references in the manifest file, it works. Thanks. @FabioZadrozny